# Javascript: Close pop up window

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a button on the main page, which will open (window.open()) a window W1 to allow user to select stuff on it. After that, user press OK button on the W1 to open window W2 (again window.open()). How can i close the W1 after the user press OK?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `window.close()` method with the name of the target window as shown below:

```
win1 = window.open("","","width=100,height=100");
okBtn.onclick = function() {
    win2 = window.open("","","width=100,height=100");
    win1.close();
}
```

Comment: i cannot control the win1 variable since that window is opened from a plugin. Is there any other way? I also tried to set in the win1 during the onclick action: window.opener = self; window.open (url2,...) but it does not work

Comment: Are the contents of win1 on your domain and available for you to edit?

Comment: yes. it is. client is made by struts framework and sent back to server. Server then forward the request and display back to client by the pop up window

Comment: Well then, if you can determine the name of the window (e.g: win1), you should be able to close it with win1.close(). You may need to look through your plugin for the appropriate window.open() function and if it doesn't have a variable name attached to it, (e.g: `win1 = window.open()`, you may have to apply one.

Answer (score 0):

On the main page you save popup into W1 and define a function that will close W1:

```
W1 = window.open("","","width=100,height=100");

function closeW1() {
    W1.close();
}
```

Now on W1 in the same place where you open W2:

```
okBtn.onclick = function() {
    W2 = window.open("","","width=100,height=100");
    window.opener.closeW1();
}
```

That's it. You're done.